# How can I use the class2llvm tool and where is its documentation?

Tags: java, llvm, bytecode

I need to transform a Java class file to LLVM IR. I have googled and heard that there exists a tool 'class2llvm' for that purpose. However,  its documentation seems missing or at least, I cannot find any. How can I install and use class2llvm, and where is its documentation?  For info, I am on Mac OS.

Comment: Downvoter please say something.

Comment: upvoting, since the downvoter did not comment.